# Can I copy my MySQL database structure to MS Access pre 2007?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I want to create a desktop version of my mysql installation without having to setup a server on my machine.

I want to make use of MS Access' query designer so I can produce complicated queries.

I know I can produce an SQL file but I've no idea how to create an MS Access database from it ?

Comment: Please be aware that you're migrating from a real database to something...else...completely...you sure about this?

Comment: How many people need to write to your database concurrently? How many rows in the largest tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to jump on the "Access sucks" bandwagon, though it can be *very* frustrating at times.

Worst case, You can start with a blank Access database (mdb file, since you specified pre-2007). Open the query designer & go to SQL view. Paste in one complete SQL statement (`CREATE TABLE...`), and run it. Fix any incompatibility errors, paste in the next (replacing the first), rinse, repeat. Be sure to do this in such order that any dependency "sources" get created before the dependents.

There may be a batch process available, but I don't know what it is offhand.

Answer (score 0):

Moving from MySQL to something like Access is heading in the wrong direction.

If you need a server-less SQL installation or package as part of your distribution (which is a pretty common requirement these days since admins don't like users to install database servers on their machines), consider [SQL Server Compact Edition (CE) or SQL Lite](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2010/07/08/SQLServerCE4SQLite.aspx). They're both fully SQL compliant (unlike Access) and will cause you far fewer headaches than Access (which sucks). (Did I mention that Access sucks? Big time?)

SQL CE is a .NET assembly that runs in-process with your app, and is very easy to work with. Also, db objects you create will be upwards-compatibile with the full-blown SQL Server. It also works very, very well with Entity Framework if you're into ORMs.

I've heard praise for SQLite, but haven't worked with it. If you're not on .NET, this should be a good way to go.

Links:

[SQL CE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2010/07/07/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft.aspx)

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: Neither of these options address the OP's stated desire to use Access QBE.

Comment: Actually, they do address it. The correct answer to "how do I jump off of the building without breaking my legs" is sometimes "use the stairs", not "get a parachute."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a viable option, but if you can set up a DSN to point to your MySQL server, you can then use FILE | GET EXTERNAL DATA | IMPORT to import your MySQL tables into a blank MDB/ACCDB. It's a one-time operation, but I don't know that there's any other option here. You should get the option to import the table schema only and not schema+data. You may have to tweak data types in the resulting tables, since the MySQL data types won't necessarily map directly to Jet/ACE data types.

Then you can carry the MDB/ACCDB file anywhere you want.